# Error 'name_taken' when trying to create a Shared Slack Channel

Tags: slack, cmp

How do you proceed when you received error 'name_taken' when trying to create a Shared Slack Channel?

Answer (score 0):

There may be different reasons why such an error is encountered. As an example, an old Slack channel was previously created with the same name.

1. Run a search in Slack to see if the name already exists
2. Create a Jira and assign to Ofir Cohen to assist with the issue
3. Connect the Jira ticket with the correct engineering team “team_nordia”